# Why am I getting "ECHO is off."?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I recently wrote the code below on a batch file:

```
@echo off
cls
chcp 65001 >nul

for /f "Delims=" %%j in (%cd%\poo.txt) do (
   echo %%j
   set /a lo=%%j+1
   echo %lo%
   pause
)
```

The file appropriately titled "poo.txt" contains a number, '0' in this case. When the code is ran, it displays this output:

```
0
ECHO is off.
Press any key to continue...
```

Everything seems to have worked, except for when the code is supposed to show 0 + 1. Instead, it outputs "ECHO is off." I don't really get this error. I've been trying to find some kind of typo or mistake in my code, but I don't see anything wrong to my knowledge.

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes, I replaced the "echo %lo%" with "echo !lo!". Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back to share that the issue is that this simple line:

```
echo %lo%
```

Should be replaced with,

```
echo !lo!
```

Anyway, goodbye.